# Spring boot app with spring boot starter web provided

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a small (working) spring boot application with spring-boot-starter-web as dependency: this application create a war (with the spring boot maven plugin); now I'm doing this test:

1. set spring-boot-starter-web as provided;
2. create another jar (shared.jar) that contains the spring-boot-starter-web dependencies;
3. add shared.jar as library inside the application server

The problem is that doing this the spring boot app doesn't start. My question is: are there some of the spring-boot-starter-web dependencies that must stay inside the application war? Thanks.

Comment: that won't work. The shared.jar doesn't contain the classes but the jar ( I assume) or only mentions it but doesn't include it. Just include it in the war where it belongs.Also adding that shared jar to your application server will give you a whole lot more headaches to deal with.

Comment: One of the great feature of Spring Boot is dependency resolution. So that you don't need to worry about configuring ton of dependencies yourself. My question is why do you want to create the separate shared.jar?

Comment: My problem is that I have a lot of spring boot app that runs on my application server. Every war is quite heavy because has inside all the dependecy. So I try to create an external fat-jar where leave all the common dependecies ( ex. spring-boot-starter-web )